# mysql fulltext MATCH,AGAINST

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a full text search on a field to match specific parts of a string. Consider a long string holding array values like 201:::1###193:::5###193:::6###202:::6. ### seperates an array element and ::: seperates key=>val. Now my understanding of match against is that it can match portions of a string in boolean mode. but when i do something in the lines of

```
`SELECT 
a.settings 
, MATCH(a.settings) AGAINST('201:::1') as relevance 
, b.maxrelevance 
, (MATCH(a.settings) AGAINST('201:::1'))/b.maxrelevance*100 as relevanceperc 
FROM 
users_profile a 
, (SELECT MAX(MATCH(settings) AGAINST('201:::1')) as maxrelevance FROM users_profile LIMIT 1) b 
WHERE 
MATCH(a.settings) AGAINST('201:::1') 
ORDER BY 
relevance DESC;`
```

Table example

CREATE TABLE `users_profile` (
  `id` int(11) default NULL,
  `profile` text,
  `views` int(11) default NULL,
  `friends_list` text,
  `settings` text,
  `points` int(11) default NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `settings` (`settings`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

i'm getting zero results. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Show table example, and mark fields you whant to be selected, please.

Comment: i've updated with the table structure. Only field settings is to be searched

Comment: I think ":" is reserved for boolean search. Have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_boolean_syntax and try to modify this setting. This might help. Also have a look at all other settings starting with "ft_" on this page.

Comment: i have, even if my string looked like test12345@@@1---pr@@@2 and i search for pr@@@2 i still get null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL fulltext indexes are designed to store natural language words. Your sample

201:::1###193:::5###193:::6###202:::6. ###

Is made up of only numbers as the significant parts, such as 201,1,192...  Because very short words are rarely useful, [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) is usually set at 4, which means none of the numbers are even in the index.

Fulltext isn't the solution to this problem.

---

If all you wanted is to **count** how many times an expression exists in the column, just use

```
(length(a.setting) - length(replace(a.setting,'201:::1',''))) / length('201:::1')
```

Comment: Yes, REGEX or LIKE, since there is a single term. Even though it will be slow.

Comment: problem is regex as far as i'm testing, cannot give me a match count per row, and that is what is the most important bit over here

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi, great idea. Will test it speed wise against the following wich has solved the problem.  SELECT SUM(a1 + a2 + a3) as matches,id
 from 
(
SELECT
id,
   CASE WHEN (settings REGEXP  '201:::1')   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as a1,
   CASE WHEN (settings REGEXP  '193:::5')   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as a2,
   CASE WHEN (settings REGEXP  '192:::1')   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as a3
   from users_profile

 )
 SQ
 group by id
 ORDER BY matches DESC

Comment: @mbouclas / oh, you're counting different matches, so you can't use the len-len(replace) trick. fyi, in mysql `CASE WHEN (settings REGEXP '201:::1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is written as just `settings REGEXP '201:::1'`

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi i used yor trick and it works briliantly. Actually it's much faster than my in large volumes. For example, 195000 rows, Searching for 14 different parameters, using your trick takes 6sec where as mine takes 7sec. Still dead slow which means i need to employ some sort of technique to avoid queries of the sort :(